# How to calculate the fitting width according to the text length and style

Tags: javascript, html

assume you have

```
<span class='class'>gfdsdfgfdsg</span>
```

How can i calculate how match size in pixel, i need for it, before it is rendered.
(I don't search for auto adjust, only calculation.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use use jquery.width() for this.

```
$('.class').width();
```

Comment: $('<span >gfdsdfgfdsg</span>').width() return 0, and i not using jquery.

Comment: @yantrab. Your entity must exist in the DOM: `$('<div/>', { text: 'apples' }).appendTo('body').width()` == 1371,  `$('<div/>', { text: 'apples' }).width()` ==
0